# AudioToolBox crash report only in iOS 12.3 above OS apple devices

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, avaudioplayer, audiotoolbox

From iOS 12.3 and above iOS versions we are getting AudioToolBox crashes, we do not know why these crashes are happening. We have Crashlytics Crash report but we are not able to debug the issue with the help of Crashlytics crash report.

I have attached the Crashlytics crash report.

Background of our application :

Our application streams the video using RTSP url and  VLC mobile kit. even when the application is sent to the background the streaming continues and the stream will try to reconnect when the stream disconnects due to some error.

While streaming the video in the background we show the user a red bar on the user iPhone.

We tried different scenarios to reproduce the issue some of them are

1) we checked if it is happening when we receive a mobile call when the user is streaming

2) We checked if interruptions from other streaming applications are causing the issue

3) We checked if Siri or getting a face time call is creating the crash

We tried all the above mentioned in debugging, as well as release, builds

find the crash report details​ below

Jul 2019 11:18:45 GMT
            # Date: 2019-07-04T10:59:00Z
            # OS Version: 12.3.1 (16F203)
            # Device: iPhone 8
            # RAM Free: 9.6%
            # Disk Free: 53.9%

```
        #22. Crashed: com.apple.coreaudio.auremoteio
        0  AudioToolbox                   0x18c489058 SampleRateConverter::SetProperty(unsigned int, unsigned int, void const*) + 192
        1  AudioToolbox                   0x18c669580 AudioConverterSetProperty + 96
        2  AudioToolbox                   0x18c51c638 AUConverterBase::SetupConverter(unsigned int, bool) + 1340
        3  AudioToolbox                   0x18c3fe948 AURemoteIO::SetupConverter(unsigned int, bool) + 224
        4  AudioToolbox                   0x18c51aed8 AUConverterBase::SetupAllConverters(bool, unsigned int) + 104
        5  AudioToolbox                   0x18c400a0c AURemoteIO::IOFormatsChanged(int) + 1420
        6  AudioToolbox                   0x18c402afc __AURIOCallbackReceiver_IOFormatsChanged_block_invoke + 96
        7  libdispatch.dylib              0x187f80a38 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
        8  libdispatch.dylib              0x187f817d4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
        9  libdispatch.dylib              0x187f5cdec _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$armv81 + 548
        10 libdispatch.dylib              0x187f5d92c _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 408
        11 libdispatch.dylib              0x187f65e08 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 584
        12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188161114 _pthread_wqthread + 304
        13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188163cd4 start_wqthread + 4

        --

        #0. com.apple.main-thread
        0  AppName           0x101169978 _gnutls_ext_deinit + 417 (extensions.c:417)
        1  AppName           0x10116f750 _gnutls_global_deinit + 416 (global.c:416)
        2  (Missing)                      0x1032313c0 (Missing)
        3  (Missing)                      0x10321a7b8 (Missing)
        4  libsystem_c.dylib              0x188038bb4 __cxa_finalize_ranges + 384
        5  libsystem_c.dylib              0x188038ec4 exit + 24
        6  UIKitCore                      0x1b4e4ed2c -[UIApplication terminateWithSuccess] + 466
        7  UIKitCore                      0x1b470adb4 __98-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability deactivateEventsOnly:withContext:forceExit:completion:]_block_invoke.261 + 344
        8  UIKitCore                      0x1b4e52dec _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 296
        9  UIKitCore                      0x1b4e4193c _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 352
        10 UIKitCore                      0x1b4e6e7ac _afterCACommitHandler + 116
        11 CoreFoundation                 0x1884d25f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
        12 CoreFoundation                 0x1884cd320 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 412
        13 CoreFoundation                 0x1884cd89c __CFRunLoopRun + 1228
        14 CoreFoundation                 0x1884cd0b0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
        15 GraphicsServices               0x18a6cd79c GSEventRunModal + 104
        16 UIKitCore                      0x1b4e47978 UIApplicationMain + 212
        17 AppName           0x1007fd1f4 main + 24 (AppDelegate.swift:24)
        18 libdyld.dylib                  0x187f928e0 start + 4

        #1. com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
        0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880d30f4 mach_msg_trap + 8
        1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880d25a0 mach_msg + 72
        2  CoreFoundation                 0x1884d2a10 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236
        3  CoreFoundation                 0x1884cd920 __CFRunLoopRun + 1360
        4  CoreFoundation                 0x1884cd0b0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
        5  Foundation                     0x188e9afac -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 300
        6  Foundation                     0x188e9ae3c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
        7  UIKitCore                      0x1b4f2d494 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
        8  Foundation                     0x188fc76a4 __NSThread__start__ + 984
        9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1881602c0 _pthread_body + 128
        10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188160220 _pthread_start + 44
        11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188163cdc thread_start + 4

        #2. GAIThread
        0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880d30f4 mach_msg_trap + 8
        1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880d25a0 mach_msg + 72
        2  CoreFoundation                 0x1884d2a10 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236
        3  CoreFoundation                 0x1884cd920 __CFRunLoopRun + 1360
        4  CoreFoundation                 0x1884cd0b0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
        5  Foundation                     0x188e9afac -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 300
        6  Foundation                     0x188ed646c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 88
        7  AppName           0x100bc9d14 +[GAI threadMain:] + 4345896212
        8  Foundation                     0x188fc76a4 __NSThread__start__ + 984
        9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1881602c0 _pthread_body + 128
        10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188160220 _pthread_start + 44
        11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188163cdc thread_start + 4

        #3. com.apple.CFSocket.private
        0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880de328 __select + 8
        1  CoreFoundation                 0x1884db6f4 __CFSocketManager + 620
        2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1881602c0 _pthread_body + 128
        3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188160220 _pthread_start + 44
        4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188163cdc thread_start + 4

        #4. com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
        0  AppName           0x100aded58 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4344933720
        1  AppName           0x100adf140 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4344934720
        2  AppName           0x100ace9bc CLSHandler + 4344867260
        3  AppName           0x100ac9d9c CLSMachExceptionServer + 4344847772
        4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1881602c0 _pthread_body + 128
        5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188160220 _pthread_start + 44
        6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188163cdc thread_start + 4

        #5. AVAudioSession Notify Thread
        0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880d30f4 mach_msg_trap + 8
        1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880d25a0 mach_msg + 72
        2  CoreFoundation                 0x1884d2a10 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236
        3  CoreFoundation                 0x1884cd920 __CFRunLoopRun + 1360
        4  CoreFoundation                 0x1884cd0b0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
        5  AVFAudio                       0x18e3b5334 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 156
        6  AVFAudio                       0x18e3dfc60 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 88
        7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1881602c0 _pthread_body + 128
        8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188160220 _pthread_start + 44
        9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188163cdc thread_start + 4

        #6. com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
        0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880d30f4 mach_msg_trap + 8
        1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880d25a0 mach_msg + 72
        2  CoreFoundation                 0x1884d2a10 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236
        3  CoreFoundation                 0x1884cd920 __CFRunLoopRun + 1360
        4  CoreFoundation                 0x1884cd0b0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
        5  CFNetwork                      0x188ae674c -[__CoreSchedulingSetRunnable runForever] + 216
        6  Foundation                     0x188fc76a4 __NSThread__start__ + 984
        7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1881602c0 _pthread_body + 128
        8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188160220 _pthread_start + 44
        9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188163cdc thread_start + 4

        #7. Thread
        0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880dffd8 poll + 8
        1  CustomSDK                         0x103661de8 _lws_plat_service_tsi + 236
        2  CustomSDK                         0x1036a3554 websocket_worker + 60
        3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1881602c0 _pthread_body + 128
        4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188160220 _pthread_start + 44
        5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188163cdc thread_start + 4

        #8. Thread
        0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880de9d4 __ulock_wait + 8
        1  libdispatch.dylib              0x187f50c20 _dispatch_ulock_wait + 56
        2  libdispatch.dylib              0x187f50d58 _dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow$VARIANT$armv81 + 48
        3  libdispatch.dylib              0x187f628a8 __DISPATCH_WAIT_FOR_QUEUE__ + 336
        4  libdispatch.dylib              0x187f624a8 _dispatch_sync_f_slow + 140
        5  AppName           0x100c397e0 -[VLCEventManager startEventLoop] + 220 (VLCEventManager.m:220)
        6  AppName           0x100c3916c EventDispatcherMainLoop + 97 (VLCEventManager.m:97)
        7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1881602c0 _pthread_body + 128
        8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188160220 _pthread_start + 44
        9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188163cdc thread_start + 4

        #9. Thread
        0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880d30f4 mach_msg_trap + 8
        1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880d25a0 mach_msg + 72
        2  CoreFoundation                 0x1884d2a10 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236
        3  CoreFoundation                 0x1884cd920 __CFRunLoopRun + 1360
        4  CoreFoundation                 0x1884cd0b0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
        5  CustomSDK                         0x103634e60 -[P2PCamera worker] + 88
        6  Foundation                     0x188fc76a4 __NSThread__start__ + 984
        7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1881602c0 _pthread_body + 128
        8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188160220 _pthread_start + 44
        9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188163cdc thread_start + 4

        #10. Thread
        0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880de328 __select + 8
        1  CustomSDK                         0x103776534 pj_sock_select + 84
        2  CustomSDK                         0x103772340 pj_ioqueue_poll + 196
        3  CustomSDK                         0x103699bc4 _pjice_worker_thread + 172
        4  CustomSDK                         0x10377329c thread_main + 84
        5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1881602c0 _pthread_body + 128
        6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188160220 _pthread_start + 44
        7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188163cdc thread_start + 4

        #11. Thread
        0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880de328 __select + 8
        1  CustomSDK                         0x103776534 pj_sock_select + 84
        2  CustomSDK                         0x103772340 pj_ioqueue_poll + 196
        3  CustomSDK                         0x103699bc4 _pjice_worker_thread + 172
        4  CustomSDK                         0x10377329c thread_main + 84
        5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1881602c0 _pthread_body + 128
        6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188160220 _pthread_start + 44
        7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188163cdc thread_start + 4

        #12. Thread
        0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880de328 __select + 8
        1  CustomSDK                         0x103776534 pj_sock_select + 84
        2  CustomSDK                         0x103772340 pj_ioqueue_poll + 196
        3  CustomSDK                         0x103699bc4 _pjice_worker_thread + 172
        4  CustomSDK                         0x10377329c thread_main + 84
        5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1881602c0 _pthread_body + 128
        6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188160220 _pthread_start + 44
        7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188163cdc thread_start + 4

        #13. Thread
        0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880de400 __semwait_signal + 8
        1  libsystem_c.dylib              0x18805556c nanosleep + 212
        2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x18805536c sleep + 44
        3  CustomSDK                         0x103697a08 _port_forward_conn_thread + 132
        4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1881602c0 _pthread_body + 128
        5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188160220 _pthread_start + 44
        6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188163cdc thread_start + 4

        #14. Thread
        0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880de328 __select + 8
        1  CustomSDK                         0x103697e88 _port_forward_io_thread + 740
        2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1881602c0 _pthread_body + 128
        3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188160220 _pthread_start + 44
        4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188163cdc thread_start + 4

        #15. Thread
        0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880de328 __select + 8
        1  AppName           0x101be7740 BasicTaskScheduler::SingleStep(unsigned int) + 91 (BasicTaskScheduler.cpp:91)
        2  AppName           0x101be70d0 BasicTaskScheduler0::doEventLoop(char volatile*) + 79 (BasicTaskScheduler0.cpp:79)
        3  AppName           0x101d6086c Demux(demux_t*) + 1420 (live555.cpp:1420)
        4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188160220 _pthread_start + 44
        5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188163cdc thread_start + 4

        #16. Thread
        0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880ddee4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
        1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18815d4d8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$armv81 + 680
        2  AppName           0x100cc08a8 vlc_cond_timedwait + 263 (thread.c:263)
        3  AppName           0x100cbff40 vlc_timer_thread + 85 (timer.c:85)
        4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1881602c0 _pthread_body + 128
        5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188160220 _pthread_start + 44
        6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188163cdc thread_start + 4

        #17. Thread
        0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880d3130 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
        1  AppName           0x100c93ad4 aout_DecPlay + 212 (dec.c:212)
        2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188160220 _pthread_start + 44
        3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188163cdc thread_start + 4

        #18. Thread
        0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880ddee4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
        1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18815d4a4 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$armv81 + 628
        2  AppName           0x100c78220 DecoderThread + 1596 (decoder.c:1596)
        3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188160220 _pthread_start + 44
        4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188163cdc thread_start + 4

        #19. AURemoteIO::IOThread
        0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880d30f4 mach_msg_trap + 8
        1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880d25a0 mach_msg + 72
        2  AudioToolbox                   0x18c401890 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Run() + 256
        3  AudioToolbox                   0x18c406800 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Entry(void*) + 76
        4  AudioToolbox                   0x18c7d94f8 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 88
        5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1881602c0 _pthread_body + 128
        6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188160220 _pthread_start + 44
        7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188163cdc thread_start + 4

        #20. Thread
        0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880deb74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
        1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1881611f8 _pthread_wqthread + 532
        2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188163cd4 start_wqthread + 4

        #21. Thread
        0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880deb74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
        1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188161138 _pthread_wqthread + 340
        2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188163cd4 start_wqthread + 4

        #22. Crashed: com.apple.coreaudio.auremoteio
        0  AudioToolbox                   0x18c489058 SampleRateConverter::SetProperty(unsigned int, unsigned int, void const*) + 192
        1  AudioToolbox                   0x18c669580 AudioConverterSetProperty + 96
        2  AudioToolbox                   0x18c51c638 AUConverterBase::SetupConverter(unsigned int, bool) + 1340
        3  AudioToolbox                   0x18c3fe948 AURemoteIO::SetupConverter(unsigned int, bool) + 224
        4  AudioToolbox                   0x18c51aed8 AUConverterBase::SetupAllConverters(bool, unsigned int) + 104
        5  AudioToolbox                   0x18c400a0c AURemoteIO::IOFormatsChanged(int) + 1420
        6  AudioToolbox                   0x18c402afc __AURIOCallbackReceiver_IOFormatsChanged_block_invoke + 96
        7  libdispatch.dylib              0x187f80a38 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
        8  libdispatch.dylib              0x187f817d4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
        9  libdispatch.dylib              0x187f5cdec _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$armv81 + 548
        10 libdispatch.dylib              0x187f5d92c _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 408
        11 libdispatch.dylib              0x187f65e08 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 584
        12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188161114 _pthread_wqthread + 304
        13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188163cd4 start_wqthread + 4

        #23. Thread
        0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880deb74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
        1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188161138 _pthread_wqthread + 340
        2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188163cd4 start_wqthread + 4

        #24. Thread
        0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880deb74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
        1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1881611f8 _pthread_wqthread + 532
        2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188163cd4 start_wqthread + 4

        #25. Thread
        0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880deb74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
        1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1881611f8 _pthread_wqthread + 532
        2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188163cd4 start_wqthread + 4

        #26. AURemoteIO::IOThread
        0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880d30f4 mach_msg_trap + 8
        1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1880d25a0 mach_msg + 72
        2  AudioToolbox                   0x18c401890 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Run() + 256
        3  AudioToolbox                   0x18c406800 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Entry(void*) + 76
        4  AudioToolbox                   0x18c7d94f8 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 88
        5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1881602c0 _pthread_body + 128
        6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188160220 _pthread_start + 44
        7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188163cdc thread_start + 4
```